# Identifying area code for a particular US city

Tags: census, postal-code

I'm trying to build a query like: "tell me what area codes (telephony area codes) overlap San Francisco" which should return 415 and 628.

Doing some [google searches](https://nationalnanpa.com/enas/npa_city_query.do) indicates that the US census data might be a good place to get this information from but I can't manage to make sense of the data on their [website](https://www.census.gov).

Any hints on how can I extract my desired information (City and overlapping area code information) from this data set?

Alternatively, are there any other, ready made, datasets with this information? Or APIs I could leverage?

Comment: It's 10 years old but here's a start: https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4f4e4a19e4b07f02db605716. Try looking for North America Numbering Plan.

Comment: Note that with overlay, you now need to know two or three area codes for any densely populated region.

Comment: @smiller so I would geocode my city (e.g. get city center point) then crosscheck that info with the area code shape files?

Comment: If it's a sufficiently large city there is a shapefile of all CBSAs / MSAs (city boundaries -- Core Based Statistical Areas --  from the Census Bureau).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core-based_statistical_area.  https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

Comment: The Census Bureau also offers several APIs but I haven't tested it and not sure if there's one specifically for the CBSAs.  https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets.html

Comment: NANPA has a website with this query. You could use code such as Python to query it directly, but I'd look further to see if they have an API endpoint; if you do connect make sure you leave enough of a timeout to not overload their system and/or appear as a bot. https://www.nationalnanpa.com/enas/npa_city_query.do